# How search query result in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

How can I search through $result for a particular value?

```
public  static function getUserLocked() {

    $result=DB::table('users')->where('status', 'locked')->get();               
    return $result;

}
```

Comment: what search you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $result = DB::table('users')
          ->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_value.'%')
          ->where('status', 'locked')
          ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do the trick:

```
$result = DB::table('users')
          ->where('column', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_value.'%')
          ->where('status', 'locked')
          ->get();
```

Column is the column from table users you will be searching on and `$search_value` would be the given input string to seek in that column for.

---

So if you for example are looking for names that contains test it will look like:

```
$search_value = "test";
$result = DB::table('users')
          ->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_value.'%')
          ->where('status', 'locked')
          ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search through the returned collection, you can use eloquent collections filter method. see https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-filter

For example:

```
$searchResults = $result->filter(function($r)
      {
         return $r->variablename == value;  //replace variablenae & value with your own
       });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend `jarektkaczyk/eloquence` package search, I'm sure it's slower than but it's free to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add `%` if you want to search for value containing, otherwise, remove `%`. Check this code:

```
public static function getUserLocked() {

    $result=DB::table('users')->where('status', 'LIKE', '%locked%')->get();               
    return $result;

}
```

*Everything that has 'locked' word will be selected*.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `result[index]->field_name`

or convert it to array using `->toarray()` and use it as 2D array `(result[index]["field_name"])`